# ClickOnce and Amazon S3

Tags: clickonce, amazon-s3

I testing the deployment of my project using clickonce. Boy was I in for a surprise. I am using quite a few 3 party dlls and my clickonce payload is 24MB. This obviously takes a while to get down to my users, especially those on VPN.

Has anyone used clickonce with Amazon S3? Can this even be done? I am thinking on publishing my deployment to such a service so my users can get a faster download.

Edit ~ My solution [here](http://iamsaif.com/archive/2009/09/03/clickonce-hosting-with-amazon-s3.aspx)

Comment: Sounds like the .NET 2.0 framework runtime, which is about 24 MB.  If you're project is simple you can make an installer with NSIS and download/install .NET 2.0 Framework only if needed.  http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Detect_and_download_the_.NET_framework.

Comment: Eh it stripped the final dot off my link so you'll have to search to find the page.

Comment: It's not the .NET framework, it's all the 3rd party components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can host your ClickOnce app anywhere that can serve the files over HTTP, including, I believe, Amazon's CloudFront service. Wherever you publish in the Internet, though, you should digitally sign your application, so users can be certain who published it, and to prevent tampering.

Comment: S3 can directly serve files of HTTP as well. CloudFront is a more of an optimization in terms of geographic distribution and use on top of S3.